# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected main_prediction to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1128, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, valueerror

I am trying to adapt an old code which used Python2.7 and Keras 1.x to Python3.7.3 and Keras 2.2.4 and TensorFlow 1.13.1. Here is how the code looks:

```
from keras.layers import Input, add, Dense, Flatten, concatenate
from keras import activations
from keras import models
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

import utils
from NGF.preprocessing import tensorise_smiles, tensorise_smiles_mp
from NGF.layers import NeuralGraphHidden, NeuralGraphOutput
from NGF.models import build_graph_conv_model
from NGF.sparse import GraphTensor, EpochIterator

# ==============================================================================
# ================================ Load the data ===============================
# ==============================================================================
print("{:=^100}".format(' Data preprocessing '))
data, labels = utils.load_delaney()

# Tensorise data
X_atoms, X_bonds, X_edges = tensorise_smiles_mp(data)
print('Atoms:', X_atoms.shape)
print('Bonds:', X_bonds.shape)
print('Edges:', X_edges.shape)

# Load sizes from data shape
num_molecules = X_atoms.shape[0]
max_atoms = X_atoms.shape[1]
max_degree = X_bonds.shape[2]
num_atom_features = X_atoms.shape[-1]
num_bond_features = X_bonds.shape[-1]

# ==============================================================================
# =============== Example 1: Building a 3-layer graph convnet  =================
# ==============================================================================
print("{:=^100}".format(' Example 1 '))

# Parameters
conv_width = 8
fp_length = 62

# Define the input layers
atoms0 = Input(name='atom_inputs', shape=(max_atoms, num_atom_features))
bonds = Input(name='bond_inputs', shape=(max_atoms, max_degree, num_bond_features))
edges = Input(name='edge_inputs', shape=(max_atoms, max_degree), dtype='int32')
print("DEBUG: edges=", K.print_tensor(edges))

# Define the convoluted atom feature layers
atoms1 = NeuralGraphHidden(conv_width, activation='relu', use_bias=False)([atoms0, bonds, edges])
atoms2 = NeuralGraphHidden(conv_width, activation='relu', use_bias=False)([atoms1, bonds, edges])

# Define the outputs of each (convoluted) atom feature layer to fingerprint
fp_out0 = NeuralGraphOutput(fp_length, activation='softmax')([atoms0, bonds, edges])
fp_out1 = NeuralGraphOutput(fp_length, activation='softmax')([atoms1, bonds, edges])
fp_out2 = NeuralGraphOutput(fp_length, activation='softmax')([atoms2, bonds, edges])

# Flatten the input before the Dense layer by summing the 3 outputs to obtain fingerprint
# final_fp = merge([fp_out0, fp_out1, fp_out2], mode='sum') # Old Keras 1.x syntax
print("DEBUG: fp_out0.get_shape()=", fp_out0.get_shape())
print("DEBUG: fp_out1.get_shape()=", fp_out1.get_shape())
print("DEBUG: fp_out2.get_shape()=", fp_out2.get_shape())
# final_fp = add([fp_out0, fp_out1, fp_out2])
final_fp = concatenate([fp_out0, fp_out1, fp_out2])
print("DEBUG: final_fp.get_shape()=", final_fp.get_shape())

# Build and compile model for regression.
main_pred = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='main_prediction')(final_fp)
print("DEBUG: main_pred.get_shape()=", main_pred.get_shape())
model = models.Model(inputs=[atoms0, bonds, edges], outputs=[main_pred])
model.compile(optimizer='adagrad', loss='mse')

# Show summary
model.summary()

# Train the model
print("DEBUG: labels.shape", labels.shape)
model.fit(x=[X_atoms, X_bonds, X_edges], y=labels, epochs=20, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
```

Essentially it is a custom made convolutional neural network, which takes 3 different arrays of variable dimensions as input and returns a scalar prediction. And this is the output when I execute it:

```
======================================== Data preprocessing ========================================
Tensorising molecules in batches...
1128/1128 [==================================================] - 1s 740us/step
Merging batch tensors...    [DONE]
Atoms: (1128, 55, 62)
Bonds: (1128, 55, 5, 6)
Edges: (1128, 55, 5)
============================================ Example 1 =============================================
DEBUG: edges= Tensor("Print:0", shape=(?, 55, 5), dtype=int32)
DEBUG: fp_out0.get_shape()= (?, 62)
DEBUG: fp_out1.get_shape()= (?, 62)
DEBUG: fp_out2.get_shape()= (?, 62)
DEBUG: final_fp.get_shape()= (?, 186)
DEBUG: main_pred.get_shape()= (?, 1)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
atom_inputs (InputLayer)        (None, 55, 62)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bond_inputs (InputLayer)        (None, 55, 5, 6)     0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
edge_inputs (InputLayer)        (None, 55, 5)        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
neural_graph_hidden_1 (NeuralGr [(None, 55, 62), (No 2720        atom_inputs[0][0]                
                                                                 bond_inputs[0][0]                
                                                                 edge_inputs[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
neural_graph_hidden_2 (NeuralGr [(None, 55, 62), (No 2720        neural_graph_hidden_1[0][0]      
                                                                 bond_inputs[0][0]                
                                                                 edge_inputs[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
neural_graph_output_1 (NeuralGr [(None, 55, 62), (No 4278        atom_inputs[0][0]                
                                                                 bond_inputs[0][0]                
                                                                 edge_inputs[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
neural_graph_output_2 (NeuralGr [(None, 55, 62), (No 4278        neural_graph_hidden_1[0][0]      
                                                                 bond_inputs[0][0]                
                                                                 edge_inputs[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
neural_graph_output_3 (NeuralGr [(None, 55, 62), (No 4278        neural_graph_hidden_2[0][0]      
                                                                 bond_inputs[0][0]                
                                                                 edge_inputs[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 55, 186)      0           neural_graph_output_1[0][0]      
                                                                 neural_graph_output_2[0][0]      
                                                                 neural_graph_output_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
main_prediction (Dense)         (None, 55, 1)        187         concatenate_1[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 18,461
Trainable params: 18,461
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
DEBUG: labels.shape (1128,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thomas/Programs/Anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-9a41784534dc>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home2/thomas/Programs/keras-neural-graph-fingerprint_Py3/examples.py', wdir='/home2/thomas/Programs/keras-neural-graph-fingerprint_Py3')
  File "/home2/thomas/Programs/pycharm-2019.1.1/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/home2/thomas/Programs/pycharm-2019.1.1/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home2/thomas/Programs/keras-neural-graph-fingerprint_Py3/examples.py", line 80, in <module>
    model.fit(x=[X_atoms, X_bonds, X_edges], y=labels, epochs=20, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
  File "/home/thomas/Programs/Anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 952, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/thomas/Programs/Anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 789, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/home/thomas/Programs/Anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 128, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected main_prediction to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1128, 1)
```

I suspect that this error is associated with the shape of the "labels" array, which is flat. What am I doing wrong?
Also, why am I getting

> DEBUG: final_fp.get_shape()= (?, 186)

but model.summary() shows

> concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 55, 186)      0

Where did this extra dimension (55) come from? Perhaps the network expects for some reason the labels to have dimensions `(1128, 55, 1)` and not `(1128, 1)`.

If you need more information please ask me and I will add more debugging print functions.

Comment: Please, anyone??? I am trying to put together a more concise example with random data in the hope that someone will answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your last Dense layer `main_predictions` is not giving a 2 dimensional output since your are not flattening the inputs of it.

> You need to use a `Flatten` layer after Convolution layers so that the
>   output of the `Dense` is 2 dimensional.

The `main_predictions` requires a 3D label but you are providing it a 2D label. Therefore, you are getting the error.

You can add a Flatten layer in the code like :

```
flatten = Flatten()( final_fp )
main_pred = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='main_prediction')( flatten )
```

And then compile the model.

Comment: What you suggest yields `"ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_1: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2"`. In fact, I thought that by concatenating the three 2D tensors I was flattening the input to the Dense layer `final_fp = concatenate([fp_out0, fp_out1, fp_out2])`. But why do I still believe that the problem is with `y` I feed to `model.fit()`..?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand from where that 55 in `main_prediction (Dense)         (None, 55, 1)` comes from! Perhaps the network expects for some reason the labels to have dimensions `(1128, 55, 1)` and not `(1128, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you mentioned as a comment that previously you had used `final_fp = merge([fp_out0, fp_out1, fp_out2], mode='sum')`. So, according to [this](http://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.2/layers/core/), you have used parameters of `mode` as `sum` not as `concat`. You are merging layer by adding them. But in new code you are using `final_fp = concatenate([fp_out0, fp_out1, fp_out2])`. So, there is difference between your old code and new code. In new code you have to use [`keras.layers.Add()`](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) to get the same functionality.

And the value error occured because shape incompabilty with your label data and output node of model. Try to change `keras.layers.Concatenate` with `keras.layers.Add`.

**Update**

```
final_fp = Input(shape=(55,62)) # I had used as input which can be replace with your final_fp
flatten_1 = Flatten()(final_fp)
main_pred = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='main_prediction')(flatten_1)

model = Model(inputs=final_fp,outputs=main_pred)
print(model.summary())
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 55, 62)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 3410)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
main_prediction (Dense)      (None, 1)                 3411      
=================================================================
Total params: 3,411
Trainable params: 3,411
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: You have one sharp eye. :) If you had two then you would have noticed that above `concatenate` I have a commented out line using `add`. Both operations produce 1D tensor, I just wanted to check if replacing `add` with `concatenate` would have any effect, but it didn't.

Comment: Btw I have both eyes good. I had also seen that you used `add`. So, if you used `add`, your code is working or not? Okay! I understand that you want to replace `add` with `concatenate` but there is difference between [add and concatenate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/361041).

Comment: There is no effect. The only difference is instead of (None, 55, 186) tensor I get (None, 55, 62).

Comment: @tevang So, after that you can use flatten and connect to Dense. See update in answer.

Comment: What I don't understand from the beginning is why on earth Keras' `Model()` thinks that the output of NeuralGraphOutput(), namely `fp_out0, fp_out1, fp_out2` have shape `(None, 55, 62)`, while before passing them to the `Model()` their shapes are `(?,62)`. 

```
DEBUG: fp_out0.get_shape()= (?, 62)
DEBUG: fp_out1.get_shape()= (?, 62)
DEBUG: fp_out2.get_shape()= (?, 62)
```

The problem starts from there. I have tried to flatten but Flatten() complains that the input must have more dimensions `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_4: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2`.

Comment: The only crude workaround I can think of is to extract the `final_fp` layer from `model` and pass it as input to a new `Sequential()` model. Then flatten. `model2 = models.Sequential(layers=[model.get_layer(name="sum_layer")]) # this is how I named 'final_fp';
model2.add(Flatten());
model2.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', name='flat_main_prediction'));
model2.compile(optimizer='adagrad', loss='mse'); model2.summary();`. But Python complains that `model` must be fittted first, namely we go back to my initial problem.

Comment: @tevang Okay, if possible can you provide runnable code may be in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com). And instead of your original data just create random data like this `X_atoms, X_bonds, X_edges = np.random.rand(1128,55,62), np.random.rand(1128,55,5,6), np.random.rand(1128,55,5)`.

Comment: the code is on github. Please look at the UPDATE on my initial post.